# Why is using std::string still needed after #include <string>?

Tags: c++, string, include, using

In order to use strings I need to include the string header, so that its implementation becomes available. But if that is so, why do I still need to add the line `using std::string`?

Why doesn't it already know about the string data type?

```
#include <string>

using std::string;

int main() {
    string s1;
}
```

Comment: Put a line using namespace std and use strings directly

Comment: Isn't that bad practice? I try to use `using` only for things i need.

Comment: @vanmarcke this is a bad practice, you used it correctly.

Comment: @vanmarcke info to why `using namespace std` is a bad practice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1 but before, you have to read about namespace (see mpiatek's answer)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `string` is defined within namespace called `std`.

you can write `std::string` everywhere where `<string>` is included but you can add `using std::string` and don't use namespace in the scope (so `std::string` might be reffered to as `string`). You can place it for example inside the function and then it applies only to that function:

```
#include <string>

void foo() {
    using std::string;

    string a; //OK
}

void bar() {
    std::string b; //OK
    string c; //ERROR: identifier "string" is undefined
}
```

Comment: so the string is not defined in the string header?

Comment: @vanmarcke it is defined in the string header within the std namespace. Take a look at the links at the end of my answer.

Answer (score 8):

`using std::string;` doesn't mean you can now use this type, but you can use this type without having to specify the namespace `std::` before the name of the type.

The following code is correct:

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string s1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the declaration of class `string` is in the namespace std. Thus you either need to always access it via std::string (then you don't need to have using) or do it as you did.

Answer (score 1):

`Namespace` is an additional feature of C++, which is defining the scope of a variable, function or object and avoiding the name collision. Here, the `string` object is defined in the `std` namespace.

`std` is the standard namespace. `cout`, `cin`, `string` and a lot of other things are defined in it.

The header `<string>` declares the various entities related to the strings library, whereas namespaces are used to group related functionality and allow use of the same names in different namespaces.